# How to setup Appium to IOS phone and Mac emulator in the cloud

Tags: c#, appium, appium-ios

I am using a MacInCloud provider for the Mac and I am trying for my Appium to connect to it.
I have entered the remote host xxx.xx.xxx.xx. the remote port xxxxx and the remote path https://foo.macincloud.com/rdpdirect.html?server=bar but for this to work I would need to enter username and password then open the simulator or if that's enough access the real IOS device connected to my pc where the Appium is installed and Visual Studio that is paired to the MAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I would need to use a higher account and pay for that to be able to use Mac in cloud.